# What checks and balances are in place to safeguard a Central Bank's independence?

Tags: central-bank

We trust the Central Banks to carry out its functions effectively and with total independence.

What are the guarantees for these institutional properties to be held to standards?

Comment: There's not one model for central bank governance. They're also not all independent. Was there a particular central bank you were interested in?

Comment: @Alex my interest is more theoretical than practical. I am interested in their powers and their influence in the values and structuring of society. Since they dictate monetary policy they can coerce people into acting according to their own ideology. Since a central bank is independent, I am curious what their interests are and if they are ever manipulated by other actors. I also want to learn why there is no democratic representation in such a powerful institution.

Comment: Again, are you sure you don’t have a bank in mind? It’s not at all true that there is no democratic representation in any central bank. In fact, most do.

Comment: The question can be both theoretical and based on a certain type of central bank governance.